# Capture image from multiple cameras at the same time instant

Tags: opencv, camera, frame-grab

My setup consists of 3 USB 2.0 cameras connected to a USB 3.0 hub and then connected to computer. Cameras are independent of each other and the hardware is not synchronized. Goal is to capture an image from all these camera when an event occur, in this case just pressing a button.

I came across this [opencv document page](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture) ,"VideoCapture::grab" & "VideoCapture::retrieve" but unable to find a simple example that i can understand/easy to use. Any help is greatly appreciated. I also see that many people are using multi threading, multi processing etc. and almost all of them are using "VideoCapture::read" rather than grab&retrieve.

Comment: What code have you got so far? What platform/OS are you on?

Comment: good question.. even i am looking for the same... using python for Linux